# How to display data in SQL from multiple tables, but only if one column data matches another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm still learning SQL, so this may just be my ignorance or inability to express in a search what I'm looking for. I've spent roughly an hour searching for some variation of the title (both here and general searches on Google). I apologize, I apparently also don't know how to format here. I'll try to clean it up now that I've posted.

I have a database of customer data that I did not design. In the GUI, there are multiple tabs, and it seems like each tab earned it's own table. The tables are linked together with a field called RecordID. In one of the tables is the Customer Data tab. The way that it's organized is that a single customer record from table A can have multiple rows in table B. I only want data from column B in table B is "CompanyA" and if column A in table B = 1.  Sample data is below.

Expected output:

```
CardNumber  LastName  FirstName  CustomerID  DataItem
------------------------------------------------------
32154       Clapton   Eric       181212      CompanyA
```

**Table A**:

```
RecordID    CardNumber    LastName    FirstName    CustomerID
---------------------------------------------------------------
1           12345         Smith       John         190201
2           12346         Jones       Sandy        190202
3           23456         Petty       Tom          190203
4           32154         Clapton     Eric         181212
5           14728         Tyler       Steven       180225
```

**Table B**:

```
RecordID    DataID    DataItem
--------------------------------
1           0         CompanyA
1           1         Yes
1           2         No
1           3         Revoked
1           4         NULL
1           5         CompanyB
2           0         CompanyB
2           1         Yes
2           2         No
2           3         NULL
2           4         24-54A
2           5         CompanyC
3           0         CompanyA
3           1         No
3           2         No
3           3         NULL
3           4         68-69B
3           5         NULL
4           0         CompanyA
4           1         Yes
4           2         Yes
5           0         CompanyB
5           1         No
5           2         No
5           5         CompanyA
```

Comment: Comments aren't the right place for information related to your question. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54594765/edit) your question instead please.

Comment: Looks better. Just make proper columns now!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to make proper columns.  As I add spaces, it just deletes them elsewhere.  Tab moves out of the post.  I can't cut and paste my Excel example, as it tries to make it an image and I'm not allowed to post images because I'm new.

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ - for future reference

Comment: You weren't using spaces, you were using tabs. Tabs don't format the same on a web page as they do in coding applications like SSMS; one reason why I have all my applications insert 4 spaces when I hit tab, and not a tab character.

Comment: That copy/paste from excel into Stackoverflow question is a new "feature" here at SO (and it sucks). To make a nice text table copy from excel into https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ and copy/paste here. That being said, the current format you have is good :) Also, don't sweat it. SQL questions are one of the most difficult to ask/format here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.CardNumber, a.LastName, a.FirstName,   a.CustomerID, b.dataitem 
from tableA A inner join TableB b
on a.recordid = b.recordid 
where b.columnA= 'CompanyA' and b.columnB = 1
```

Comment: This is a good answer. If you added some explanation about why this works it would be a great answer.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.  It's funny, I had something similar, but it was returning all results where 'CompanyA' appeared in the dataItem column regardless of the value of DataID.  This is important where a customer used to work for one company, but now works for another.  Previous employers are kept in the notes (DataID 5 instead of 0). Not sure what's different really, but formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you're looking for is a `JOIN`. In this case specifically you need an `INNER JOIN`. Joins connects two tables together based on criteria you specify (such as matching values in fields) and merges the result into one table in the output.

Here's an example to suit your scenario:

```
SELECT 
  A.CardNumber, 
  A.LastName, 
  A.FirstName,   
  A.CustomerID, 
  B.DataItem
FROM
  TableA A 
  INNER JOIN TableB B -- join tableB onto tableA
    ON A.RecordID = B.RecordID -- in the ON clause you specify criteria by you match the fields
WHERE 
  B.columnA = 'CompanyA' 
  AND B.columnB = 1
```

Here's the relevant [SQL Server Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017)

Also I'd advise you to potentially take a comprehensive introductory SQL tutorial, and/or find a book. A good one will introduce all of the basic, key concepts such as this to you in a logical way, then you're not grasping in the dark trying to google things for which you don't know the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution,

```
select a.CardNumber,  a.LastName,  a.FirstName,  a.CustomerID,  b.DataItem from 
tableA a
inner join tableB b
on (a.RecordID = b.RecordID)
where
b.DataItem='CompanyA'
b.RecordID=1;
```

Le me know if the result is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

At the database engine level, if you are using Microsoft technology, the most efficient structure is to use an indexed foreign key constraint on Table B, and a Primary Surrogate Key (PSK) column on Table A. The Primary Surrogate Key in your case is on the Parent table, Table A, and is called RecordID. The foreign key column with the FKC is on Table B, on the column named RecordID. Once you verify that there is a FKC (foreign key constraint on Table B, which pins both columns named RecordID between both tables on matched values), then address the GUI. At the GUI, between the tabs, you generally indicate you have a parent table with a unique set of Record IDs (one column named Record ID with absolutely unique values in each row and no empty rows on that column). There will also be child tables on each Tab in your GUI, and those are bound to the parent table in a "1 to Many (1:M)" fashion, where 1 parent has many children. Your commentary or question indicates that you also want to filter, where Record ID on the child in one of the related tabs equates to the integer value 1 on the Record ID. So, there needs to be a query somewhere:

```
SELECT [columns] 
FROM [Table B] 
INNER JOIN [Table A] 
    ON A.RecordID = B.RecordID 
    AND B.RecordID = 1;
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but let me give you an example that resembles the what i think you are asking.

```
SELECT a.*, b.DataItem FROM A a INNER JOIN B b
            ON a.RecordID = b.RecordID AND
                b.DataItem = `CompanyA`
```